# Display commas for large numbers in a single textbox of a calculator

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I have a textbox that displays numbers and operators upon clicking the according button on the calculator then gets results upon clicking the = button.

The problem is, I'm trying to get it to display commas when the numbers are over 999.99 and calculate them. It works fine with one number with commas but not the other, only those without it (as long as they are input last).

For instance:

```
1,111 + 33333 (works in calculation)
1,111 + 22,222 (doesn't work)
33333 + 1,111 (doesn't work either)
```

Here's a bit of my code:

```
Private Sub ButtonClickMethod(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button0.Click, Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, PlusButton.Click, EqualButton.Click
Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    'numbers
    If button.Name = "Button0" Then
        TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + "0"
    End If
    If button.Name = "Button1" Then
        Dim val1 As String
        val1 = TextBox.Text + "1"
        TextBox.Text = val1
        TextBox.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(val1).ToString("#,##")
    End If
    If button.Name = "Button2" Then
        Dim val2 As String
        val2 = TextBox.Text + "2"
        TextBox.Text = val2
        TextBox.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(val2).ToString("#,##")
    End If
    If button.Name = "Button3" Then
        TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + "3"
    End If
    'operations
    If button.Name = "PlusButton" Then
        TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + "+"
    End If
    'equal/result
    If button.Name = "EqualButton" Then
        Dim equation As String = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", String.Empty)
        Dim results = New DataTable().Compute(equation, Nothing)
        TextBox.Text = results
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using ToString("#,##") and then removing the comma again is not a great idea.  Your profile says that you live in the USA, is that accurate?  Your code says it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that after having pressed the `+` operator, you text box might contain two numbers. If you want to format them, you need to separate the string in to 1st number, operator and 2nd number and format the two numbers separately. `val1` and `val2` can contain something like `"13.2+5"` and cannot be converted with `ToDecimal`.

I also would extract the logic into reusable methods, instead of repeating it over and over for the different buttons.

The text box should only be used for the display and not as storage for the input.

```
Private _input As String

Private Sub TypeDigit(ByVal key As Char)
    _input += key
    Display()
End Sub

Private Sub TypeOperator(ByVal key As Char)
    _input += " " & key & " "
    Display()
End Sub

Private Sub Execute(ByVal key As Char)
    Select Case key
        Case "="c
            _input = Calculate(_input)
        Case "C"c
            _input = ""
        Case Else
    End Select

    Display()
End Sub
```

We still have to declare the two methods `Calculate` and `Display`. Note that we have 3 input methods. Each one of them calls `Display` at the end. `Display` will do all the formatting and place the result into the text box.

The click events handlers:

```
Private Sub buttonClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Execute("C"c)
End Sub

Private Sub buttonDecimalPoint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TypeDigit("."c)
End Sub

Private Sub button0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TypeDigit("0"c)
End Sub

...

Private Sub button9_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TypeDigit("9"c)
End Sub

Private Sub buttonEquals_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Execute("="c)
End Sub

Private Sub buttonPlus_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    TypeOperator("+"c)
End Sub

' other operators here...
```

The `Display` method is quite tricky, because we might have to format incomplete numbers. E.g. numbers starting or ending with a decimal point or numbers having trailing zeroes. We must ensure to preserve those during formatting. I ended up with

```
Private Sub Display()
    Dim parts As String() = _input.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim display As String = ""
    Dim n As Decimal

    For Each part As String In parts
        If part = "." Then
            display += "0."
        ElseIf part.EndsWith(".") AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(part.Substring(0, part.Length - 1), n) Then
            display += n.ToString("#,##0") & "."
        ElseIf Decimal.TryParse(part, n) Then
            Dim decimalPoint As Integer = part.IndexOf("."c)

            If decimalPoint >= 0 Then
                Dim numDecimals As Integer = part.Length - decimalPoint - 1
                display += n.ToString("#,##0." & New String("0"c, numDecimals))
            Else
                display += n.ToString("#,##0")
            End If
        Else
            display += " " & part & " "
        End If
    Next

    textBoxDisplay.Text = display
End Sub
```

I didn't implement the `Calculate` method. I leave it up to you. You will have to start as in the `Display` method by splitting up the input into parts.